# Log4j2-JDBC Appender

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

How to connect jdbc appender in log4j2????
im new to log4j2.0
any one help me to solve this??

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="error">
  <appenders>
    <Jdbc name="databaseAppender" tableName="application_log">
      <DriverManager url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE" username="system" password="system" />
      <Column name="level" pattern="%level" />
      <Column name="logger" pattern="%logger" />
      <Column name="message" pattern="%message" />
    </Jdbc>
  </appenders>
  <loggers>
    <root level="warn">
      <appender-ref ref="databaseAppender"/>
    </root>
  </loggers>
</configuration
```

Answer (score 2):

Your configuration looks okay. (Similar to the docs http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#JDBCAppender)

What is the problem? Are you getting an error? Do you have an error code or a stack trace?

If you're not getting an error but nothing is happening, you can try setting `<configuration status="trace"` in your config file. This will output log4j2 internal log messages to the console and may help diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check the version of Log4j2.

Starting with [version 2.11](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2185), the library supports DriverManagerConnectionSource - "[A quick and dirty way to get off the ground, no connection pooling](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#JDBCAppender)".

Just for example:

```
<JDBC name="databaseAppender" tableName="application_log">
     <DriverManager connectionString="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE" 
        driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        username="system" 
        password="system" />
    <Column name="level" pattern="%level" />
    <Column name="logger" pattern="%logger" />
    <Column name="message" pattern="%message" />
</JDBC>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we can't use DriverManager inside JDBC appender. You need to get connection using JNDI name or create connectionFactory class that have static method which return connection object.

Following link will help you.
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#JDBCAppender

Here is your modified code, I think it should work.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="error">
  <appenders>
    <Jdbc name="databaseAppender" tableName="application_log">
      <ConnectionFactory class="net.example.db.ConnectionFactory" method="getDatabaseConnection" />
      <Column name="level" pattern="%level" />
      <Column name="logger" pattern="%logger" />
      <Column name="message" pattern="%message" />
    </Jdbc>
  </appenders>
  <loggers>
    <root level="warn">
      <appender-ref ref="databaseAppender"/>
    </root>
  </loggers>
</configuration
```

Here is ConnectionFactory.java code. You need to change user, pass and connection as per your database.

```
package net.example.db;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverManagerConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource;
import org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool;

public class ConnectionFactory {
    private static interface Singleton {
        final ConnectionFactory INSTANCE = new ConnectionFactory();
    }

    private final DataSource dataSource;

    private ConnectionFactory() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("user", "logging");
        properties.setProperty("password", "abc123"); // or get properties from some configuration file

        GenericObjectPool<PoolableConnection> pool = new GenericObjectPool<PoolableConnection>();
        DriverManagerConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new DriverManagerConnectionFactory(
                "jdbc:mysql://example.org:3306/exampleDb", properties
        );
        new PoolableConnectionFactory(
                connectionFactory, pool, null, "SELECT 1", 3, false, false, Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
        );

        this.dataSource = new PoolingDataSource(pool);
    }

    public static Connection getDatabaseConnection() throws SQLException {
        return Singleton.INSTANCE.dataSource.getConnection();
    }
}
```

This is working for me. It should work for you also.

Comment: How to do this for spring boot application ?